# A line bundle is torsion iff its pull-back is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a finite flat morphism of varieties. Probably some assumptions on $f$ are required, but I have often seen the following claim being used:

> If a line bundle $L$ on $Y$ is such that $f^\ast L\simeq\mathcal{O}_X$ then $L$ is torsion.

Conversely, if $L\in\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$ is torsion let $f\colon X\to Y$ be the associated covering. Then

> $f^\ast L\simeq\mathcal{O}_X$

How to prove these assumptions?

Comment: What do you mean by "is torsion"?  I would know what "is torsion-free" meant but not simply "is torsion".  I thought that "torsion" was something a bundle **had**, not something it **was**!

Comment: @user247327. A line bundle **is** an element of a group

Comment: This is already false for $X=Y$ and $f=$ identity.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you Georges. I will edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is a finite flat map, there exists maps $f^*:\mathrm{Pic}\, Y\to \mathrm{Pic}\, X$ and a map $f_*$ in the reverse direction, with the composite $f_*f^*$ multiplication by $\deg f$. $f_*$ is defined as follows. For a line bundle $M$ on $X$, $f_*(M)\in \mathrm{Pic}\, Y$ is $\Lambda^df_*M\otimes (\Lambda^d f_*\mathcal{O}_X)^{-1}$, where in the last expression, $f_*M$ is the direct image as coherent sheaves and $d=\deg f$. So, under such a map, if $f^*L=\mathcal{O}_X$, then $L$ is torsion. Conversely if $L$ is torsion, you can construct a variety $X=\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L\oplus L^2\oplus\cdots \oplus L^{d-1}$, where $d=\mathrm{ord}\, L$, $f:X\to Y$ the induced finite flat map and $f^*L=\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg, Thank you, will correct it. Also, missed a very important assumption of flatness.

Comment: Dear Mohan. In the second case, why is $f^\ast L=\mathcal{O}_X$ ?

Comment: $f^*L=L\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} \mathcal{O}_X=L\oplus\cdots \oplus L^{d-1}\oplus \mathcal{O}_Y$, since $L^d=\mathcal{O}_Y$. Then you get an $\mathcal{O}_X$ module map from $\mathcal{O}_X$ to $f^*L$ by sending 1 to the 1 (in the last direct summand) of $f^*L$ and one checks that this is an isomorphism.